# shopping-cart.hbs page is not getting rendered

Tags: html, node.js, handlebars.js

This is my routing file where i am trying to render shopping.hbs file.
I am getting the correct output on console.log.Shopping-cart.hbs file is in my shop folder inside Views.

```
router.get('/shopping-cart',function(req,res,next){
    if(!req.session.cart)
    {
        return res.render('shop/shopping-cart',{products:null});    
    }
    var cart=new Cart(req.session.cart);
    console.log(cart.totalPrice);
    console.log(cart.generateArray());
    res.render('shop/shopping-cart',{products:cart.generateArray(),totalPrice: cart.totalPrice});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the code for generatingArray. If I replace passing the array into the page then the page renders successfully.

```
module.exports=function Cart(oldCart) {
    this.items=oldCart.items || {};
    this.totalQty=oldCart.totalQty || 0;
    this.totalPrice=oldCart.totalPrice || 0;

    this.add=function(item,id)
    {
        var storedItem=this.items[id];
        if(!storedItem)
        {
            storedItem=this.items[id]={item:item,qty:0,price:0};
        }
        storedItem.qty++;
        storedItem.price=storedItem.qty*storedItem.item.price;
        this.totalQty++;
        this.totalPrice+=storedItem.item.price;
    };

    this.generateArray=function(){
        var arr=[];
        for(var id in this.items){
            arr.push(this.items[id]);
        }
        return arr;
    };
};
```

Here is the output of console.

```
6000
[ { item: 
     { _id: '5a033713520a9414e9e6e0ac',
       imagePath: 'https://media.contentapi.ea.com/content/dam/ea/easports/fifa/features/2017/cristiano-ronaldo/june5/ronaldo-share.jpg',
       title: 'FIFA 2018',
       description: 'PC Game',
       price: 2000,
       __v: 0 },
    qty: 3,
    price: 6000 } ]
```

This is my shopping-cart.hbs file where i am iterating the products.

```
    {{ # if products }}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
            <ul class="list-group">
                {{ # each products }}
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <span class="badge">{{this.qty}}</span>
                    <strong>{{this.item.title}}</strong>
                    <span class="label label-success">Rs {{this.price}}</span>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" type="button" datatoggle="dropdown">Action<span class="caret"></span></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Reduce by 1</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Remove all</li>


                </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            {{ /each }}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
        <strong>Total : {{ totalPrice }}</strong>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Checkout</button>
    </div>
</div>
{{ else }}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
        <h2>No items in Cart</h2>
    </div>
</div>
{{ /if }}
```

Here is the configuration setting for handle bar

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var hbs=require('express-handlebars');
var session=require('express-session');
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var passport=require('passport');
var flash=require('connect-flash');
var validator=require('express-validator');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/shopping');
require('./config/passport');
var MongoStore=require('connect-mongo')(session);
var index = require('./routes/index');
var userRouter=require('./routes/user');

var app = express();


// view engine setup
app.engine('.hbs',hbs({extname:'hbs',defaultLayout:'layout',layoutsDir:__dirname + '/views'}));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `console.log` calls to have an idea about the arguments being provided to the template?

Comment: Added the output of logs. Can you check now

Comment: Are you getting any html output? Or it's just like do you have no products in your shopping cart (the else block indeed)?

Comment: no i am not getting anything on the html page. Even if i dont have any product in cart then else block also has "No item in cart written" ,even that is not getting displayed. Although i have the products in cart as you can see in the console

Comment: Just one more question (even I think I can guess the answer). Do you have more templates working properly? Just to know if the template engine it's working somewhere else in your application. In that way, it would be nice to see the lines of code where you set up the template engine.

Comment: Yes i have other templates working.I have added the configuration code for handlebars

Comment: I have found the error. There is a problem in generating the array.I have added that code. Please help me in finding the error

Comment: Try with this: `var items = this.items; Object.keys(this.items).map(function(id) { return this.items[id];}) `

Comment: It did not worked

Comment: Sorry, but for some reason I'm not able to edit my previous comment. Instead of returning `this.items[id]`, return `items[id]`

Comment: this is also Not working

Comment: Finally got the solution. Inside shopping-cart.hbs if and each were wrongly closed. They should be closed like {{/tag}} instead of {{ /tag}}.

Comment: Good catch! I'm sorry for not being helpful in this case.

Comment: No problem. It was a very minor error